# Marker Drag Event in GWT openLayers

Tags: gwt, openlayers, gwt-openlayers

How do I create a drag event for a openlayers Marker? I have a Marker that inherits the openlayers Marker class, and I need to be able to drag the Marker

Comment: there is a track in openlayers about dragging a marker that you can check out: http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/sandbox/tschaub/feature/lib/OpenLayers/Control/DragMarker.js?rev=3459